# Webpack + react throw error with socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, webpack

I have a webpack server running with react, everything was working fine until I wanted to add socket.io, after that I was getting plenty of errors, still can't figure it our how to fix it..this is my code. Before webpack I was using express js and everything was looking good, any tips would be very apreciated;)

////main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(8081);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('room', data => {
        socket.join(data);
        io.to(room).emit('msg', 'in the room!')
    })
})

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

/// App.js

```
import React from 'react';
let socket;
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        socket = io();
    }
    clicked() {
        socket.emit('room', 'abc')
        socket.on('message', data => alert(data))
    }
    render() {
        return (<div>
                <button>Join </button>
            </div>);
    }
}

export default App;
```

///index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>React</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
<script src='bundle.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.8.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a socket.io client side npm package that's probably better to use than the CDN. Also what's the error that's being thrown?

Comment: I dont have enought characters to post the errors here, I'm not really sure if that's how it works tbh. I've seen people declaring the socket events ins states, I'm still confused, first time when I'm coding on webpack..

Comment: Enough characters? Don't post the error as a comment, update your original question with the error. It's super hard to diagnose what your problem is if we don't what the error is!

Comment: Dude, I've been reading the errors and that looked so unfamiliar, that I started to ask myself If that realy makes dense for the compiler. I'm coming from express js, was wondering If there's some guys Here used to webpack..

Comment: pardon me but what is webpack?

Comment: Dude, I'm asking for help here, If You can offer any  that's great, but please let's not start spamming here..

Comment: I've setup webpack with socket.io many times so it's highly likely I can help you. The thing I'm confused about mainly is in your `main.js` file you have both client side and server side code mixed together which doesn't really make sense. Feel free to pull down this repo to see how it should be setup https://github.com/alex-wilmer/rater

Comment: @sova https://webpack.github.io/

Comment: @azium, this git looks a lot more anvanced for me, I will try to split the main js,  in two parts. I've seen there that You got two versions, development and production. What's the difference?

Comment: Production builds usually contain minified files, remove console logs etc. Just remember that webpack is only for client side code. If you want to use sockets you'll still need an express server separate from your webpack/react front end code

Comment: @azium ty for clarifying this to me, now kinda know whatbI have to do, ty ;)